# How to copy a subproject to the container in a multi container Docker app with Docker Compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to build a multi container docker app with docker compose. My project structure looks like this:

```
docker-compose.yml
...
webapp/
   ...
   Dockerfile
api/
   ...
   Dockerfile
```

Currently, I am just trying to build and run the `webapp` via `docker compose up` with the correct build context. When building the `webapp` container directly via `docker build`, everything runs smoothly.

However, with my current specifications in the `docker-compose.yml` the line `COPY . /webapp/` in `webapp/Dockerfile` (see below) copies the whole parent project to the container, i.e. the directory which contains the `docker-compose.yml`, and not just the `webapp/` sub directory.
For some reason the line `COPY requirements.txt /webapp/` works as expected.

What is the correct way of specifying the build context in `docker compose`? Why is the `.` in the Dockerfile interpretet as relative to the `docker-compose.yml`, while the `requirements.txt` is relative to the `Dockerfile` as expected? What am I missing?

Here are the contents of the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  frontend:
    container_name: "pc-frontend"
    volumes:
        - .:/webapp
    env_file:
      - ./webapp/.env
    build:
      context: ./webapp
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
```

and `webapp/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1

# set working directory
WORKDIR /webapp

# copy dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /webapp/

# install dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy project
COPY . /webapp/  # does not work as intended

# add entrypoint to app
# ENTRYPOINT ["start-gunicorn.sh"]

CMD [ "ls", "-la" ]  # for debugging

# expose port
EXPOSE 5000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `COPY` directive is (probably) working the way you expect.  But, you have `volumes:` that are overwriting the image content with something else.  Delete the `volumes:` block.

The image build sequence is working exactly the way you expect.  `build: { context: ./webapp }` uses the `webapp` subdirectory as the *build context* and sends it to the Docker daemon.  When the Dockerfile for example `COPY requirements.txt .` it comes out of this directory.  If you, for example, `docker-compose run frontend pip freeze`, you should see the installed Python packages.

After the image is built, Compose starts a container, and at that point `volumes:` take effect.  When you say `volumes: ['.:/webapp']`, here the `.` before the colon refers to the directory containing the `docker-compose.yml` file (and not the `webapp` subdirectory), and then it hides everything in the `/webapp` directory in the container.  So you're replacing the image's `/webapp` (which had been built from the `webapp` subdirectory) with the current directory on the host (one directory higher).

You should usually be able to successfully combine an ordinary host-based development environment and a Docker deployment setup.  Use a non-Docker Python virtual environment to build the application and run its unit tests, then use `docker-compose up --build` to run integration tests and the complete application.  With a setup like this, you don't need to deal with the inconveniences of the Python runtime being "somewhere else" as you're developing, and you can safely remove the `volumes:` block.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Deleting the volumes block did the job. Thanks also for the tips on the dev environment.